# Js - Event Listener working only once after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Event listener code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("pagenumber").addEventListener( "keydown", function( e ) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if ( keyCode === 13 ) {
            Dajaxice.gallery.gallerypages(Dajax.process, {'p': document.getElementById('pagenumber').value })
        }}, false);

    });
</script>
```

The problem is when i press on the input element, change the page number and press enter it only works the first time, after the page reload.

What could be my problem?

Comment: How come you are not entirely using jquery this handle this?

Comment: What is `Dajaxice`? How do you know the event listener does not work, and not the method it calls?

Comment: I have an input element, when i write the page number, Dajaxice will do the ajax job (Ajax for Django). The next page simply becomes loaded. But when i try to change page again, It doesn't work anymore.

Comment: So, the Ajax result overwrites the input element and places a new one there?

Comment: It will read the page number in the input element and get the images and load them in the gallery div according to the page number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say much about the Dajaxice object, but this seems a lot easier for the event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("keydown", "#pagenumber", function(e) {
        if ( e.which === 13 ) {
             Dajaxice.gallery.gallerypages(Dajax.process, {'p': this.value });
        }
    });
});
```

This is delegated to the document level, so if the input element is replaced by ajax, it should still work ?

Comment: This is way much easier and less code and more cleaner but it didn't work. Does this need a new version of jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready();` is obsolete. You should use `$(document).on("ready", function());`.
Also `.on()` applies the same functions to the new elements are added to the document with the same class or ID. Try it and luck!